# Does Vaadin 7 TextField support multiline mode?

Tags: vaadin, textfield, multiline

I can see

```
The text editor supports both multiline and single line modes,
default is one-line mode.
```

in documentation, but cannot find any hint how to switch it. setHeight doesnt work and setRows method (mentioned probably for Vaadin 6) doesnt exist. I need textarea, but normal text, no HTML presentation. Autosizeheight is welcome. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a class `TextArea` (https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextArea.html) which implements your desired functionality. `TextField` doesn't support a multi-line mode.